# Synchronizing scrollbars, scrollTop and scroll event loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been playing around synchronizing two scrollbars on a web application using Javascript and jQuery (1.11.3). So far what I've been doing is any time a scroll event happens on one div, I use scrollTop to adjust the position on the other div:

```
$left = $("#left")
$right = $("#right")

$left.scroll(function () {
    $right.scrollTop($left.scrollTop());
});

$right.scroll(function () {
    $left.scrollTop($right.scrollTop());
});
```

(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcano/8xaw2896/2/)

The problem comes from scrollTop triggering a scroll event on the element it's called from, creating a loop and making it misbehave on some browsers.

Javascript events are queued, so toggling a flag before and after a call to scrollTop is not working (and could possibly backfire). So I came up with this solution:

```
$left = $( "#left" )
scrollLeft = []

$right = $( "#right" )
scrollRight = []

$left.scroll( function () {
    if ( !scrollRight.pop() ) {
        scrollLeft.push( true );
        $right.scrollTop( $left.scrollTop() );
    }
} );

$right.scroll( function () {
    if ( !scrollLeft.pop() ) {
        scrollRight.push( true );
        $left.scrollTop( $right.scrollTop() );
    }
} );
```

(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcano/8xaw2896/4/)

This actually works, even though the scroll event is triggered on the other div the code is not executed and the loop is broken. I'm using a queue with push and pop in case some browser calls event handlers in some weird way; possibly using a single boolean variable could suffice to guard scrollTop.

My question is, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `This actually works, even though the scroll event is triggered on the other div the code is not executed and the loop is broken.` Sounds an awful lot like it doesn't work.

Comment: @EaziLuizi, in relation to Mast's comment, that would make this question off-topic for Code Review

Comment: @Mast I cannot avoid the event from being triggered if I'm using scrollTop, so I want to break the scroll event loop. Do you know another way of doing it and avoiding the scroll event call, maybe not using scrollTop?